# How can I use persimmons in a cooked dish?

Tags: culinary-uses, fruit

I've recently had my first taste of a persimmon, having no idea how it tastes or how it should be eaten, I cut it into slices and ate it like an apple.

It is a very interesting sweet taste, and would like to know how I can incorporate it into a cooked meal or dish?

Comment: I usually just eat it raw after it's ripened. That's the only time i've had a persimmon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Raw**

Personally, growing up I've usually just eat it raw after it's ripened. That's the only form that i've a experienced a persimmon.

Nonethless, a quick google reveals use as a sauce:

> This morning, I cooked the last of the mushy persimmons into a second
>   batch of persimmon sauce.  The first, served over bread pudding on a
>   whim one evening, was so popular that it was deemed worthy of the last
>   persimmons.  It’s simple and delicious, primarily because, as I
>   discovered, a generous serving of  nutmeg and a bit of meyer lemon is
>   the best way to season persimmon anything!

Source: [Oakland Garden Kitchen](http://oaklandgardenkitchen.wordpress.com/2010/01/10/persimmon-season/)

In this article, Oakland Garden Kitchen blogger, also lists a recipes for [persimmon bread](http://oaklandgardenkitchen.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/jesss-persimmon-bread.pdf) published by David Lebovitz. Lebovitz has a very comprehensive [blog article about persimmons](http://www.davidlebovitz.com/2005/11/persimmon-bread/).

**Persimmon in Bread**

In this blog, he provides an adaptation of [James Beard's](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0679755047), "Beard on Bread", Persimmon Bread recipe. If you don't like this version of the recipe. Epicurean has [another version](http://recipes.epicurean.com/recipe/21405/persimmon-bread.html).

**Persimmon as an Entree**

Wine Press NW also once published a recipe of use of persimmon as a [glaze for salmon](http://www.northwest-wine.com/recipe-grilled-ahi.html).

Answer (score 3):

I have an aunt who occasionally brings us TONS of persimmons. While we do prefer them raw, I've tried them in several baked dishes in an effort to use them up. My favorite was apple-persimmon pie. I made a classic apple pie, and replaced 1/2 of the fruit with slices of persimmons (fairly crispy, fuyu variety persimmons, not the squishy type). It was very good. I have also added about 1/2 a cup of minced persimmon to a classic banana bread recipe for a nice flavorful fruity addition.

Comment: That sounds delicious, I will definitely have to try it.